# Run button isn't working

Tags: android, gradle

First of all, I'm not good at English, and I'm new at developing apps. Please consider this when explaining things to me.

I had added source for Bluetooth. During that, I changed and added some code to the gradle file. Since then, the Run button doesn't work anymore.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ebookfrenzy.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
If you need more information about this, leave a meassage.
Thanks for reading.

**EDIT:** Here is part of error messages in Android Monitor

```
08-23 09:04:56.865 3340-5450/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.contacts.metadata
08-23 09:05:08.418 5708-5958/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
08-23 09:05:33.704 6127-6127/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.gms.car.CarService has leaked ServiceConnection fmj@d6bf3b1 that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.car.CarService has leaked ServiceConnection fmj@d6bf3b1 that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1092)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:986)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1303)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1286)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
at ivw.a(:com.google.android.gms:120)
at ivw.a(:com.google.android.gms:137)
at fmj.h(:com.google.android.gms:76)
at fmj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:64)
at fpn.i(:com.google.android.gms:551)
at com.google.android.gms.car.CarChimeraService.onBind(:com.google.android.gms:165)
at com.google.android.chimera.container.ServiceProxy.onBind(:com.google.android.gms:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2904)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Everytime you edit the gradle file, you need to sync again before you can run the app. It might be that you didn't do that yet. Android Studio notifies you with a "Sync Now" button in the upper right corner in a yellow bar.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but i did already but it's still not working...

Comment: Another suggestion: When you click the [Build] > [Rebuild Project] menu, do you get any errors? These errors might pop up in the Messages log. If so, please paste them in your post.

Comment: I added some messages. should i add all the messages?

Comment: The messages you added are from the Android log. This means these messages come from the app you are already running on your device. Please add messages from the `Messages` tag instead of the `Android Monitor` tab.

Comment: Clean your project and then try to rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I had decided to restart and made a new project.